# Carrierwave resize_to_fit not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick

Hi i'm trying to resize an image to a size of `width 1135px and auto height`(so that i can resize it in css) . and for this i'm adding following line in uploader

```
  version :large_cover_photo do
      resize_to_fit(1135, 10000)
  end
```

Same goes for .

```
  version :large_cover_photo do
      resize_to_fit(1135, 0)
  end

  version :large_cover_photo do
      resize_to_fit(1135, nil)
  end
```

**Even if i specify to 300px height in uploader.** it does not work
This is resizing image to `width 1135px` but height not working accordingly . and if i try to resize height through css , it's making significance difference on width too . kindly have a look on images attached
[image]

**This second image is when i resize it through inline css(not touching widht in css)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  version :large_cover_photo do
    process resize_to_fill: [1135,300]
  end
```

Note the key word process it will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

According to carrierwave's documentation [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), I think you should use **Square Brackets [ ]** instead of **usual brackets ()** when defining versions, So your code should be like...

```
version :large_cover_photo do
  resize_to_fit: [1135, 10000]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
`resize_to_fill` instead of `resize_to_fit`